# Not able to load model in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a model called register_model.php, which I have loaded in a function in my controller (register_controller.php). Model file is placed into model folder itself. Still, I get this error.

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: register_model

register_controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register_controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

//    function index()
//    {
//        
//    }

    public function register() {

        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            //user is already logged in
            redirect('index.php');
        } 
        else {
            //init
            //$data['country_list']=$this->config->item('um_country_list');
             $data['username'] = '';
             $data['firstname'] = '';
            $data['lastname'] = '';
            $data['email'] = '';

           // $data['password'] = '';
            //$data['userlevel'] = '';

            //load rules
            $rules = $this->config->item('um_register_rules');
            //default msg
            $data['msg'] = $this->lang->line('um_form_msg');
            $this->load->model('register_model');
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                //the user has submitted the form
                //get the user input

                $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
                $data['firstname'] = $this->input->post('firstname');
                $data['lastname'] = $this->input->post('lastname');
                $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
                $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
                //$data['userlevel'] = $this->input->post('userlevel');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules); //check with the rules
                if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                    //validation failed
                    $data['msg'] = $this->lang->line('um_form_error');
                    $this->load->view('user_register_form', $data);
                } else {
                    //validation passed
                    $dbdata = array(


                        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                        'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                        'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                        //'userlevel' => $this->input->post('userlevel')

                    );

                    $this->register_model->register_user($dbdata);

                    $data['msg']=$this->lang->line('um_form_activate');
                    //render the view
                    $this->load->view('um_msg', $data);
                }
            } else {
                //render the view
                $this->load->view('user_register_form', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

register_model.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Register_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function register_user($dbdata) {
            $this->db->insert('users', $dbdata);
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: add your controller and model code

Comment: Added controller and model code.

Comment: Everything seems correct... Maybe a letter case problem with your filenames ?

Comment: There is none. Everything is in small case and that's the reason I'm not able to get the problem.

Comment: Is this strange problem solved, in meantime?

Comment: No, I cannot get hold of the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should include your model inside your controller, try to include after `parent::__construct`

This should look like so:

class Registration extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('register_model');
}
```

or if you using this model in most controllers you can include it using autoload, go to /config/autoload.php search for $autoload['model'] and add your model inside the suitable array

Answer (score 0):

First of all load your model in your controller ..

```
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('register_model');
}
```

This will work for you...

Comment: Its not working..it is present in the model folder only..the classname is Register_model and the file is register_model.php..then why is this issue coming?

Comment: I made a different model and used it and it worked. Thanks anyway.